# Node - define request default does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js

I trying to define general request defaults but it does not seems to work, as only the 'body' & 'url' become part of the request structure.

Here's the code:

```
const { URL } = require('url');
const request = require('request-promise-native');
const config = require('./config');

let GIT_API_URL = new URL(config.CI_PROJECT_URL);
GIT_API_URL.pathname = '/v4/api';
GIT_API_URL = GIT_API_URL.toString();

const gitLabDefaultRequest = request.defaults({
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'PRIVATE-TOKEN': config.GIT_API_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  },
  json: true,
  simple: true,
  timeout: 15000,
  resolveWithFullResponse: true,
});

async function createCommit(commitRequestBody) {
  const options = {
    url: `${GIT_API_URL}/projects/${config.PROJECT_ID}/repository/commits`,
    body: commitRequestBody,
  };

  const response = await gitLabDefaultRequest.post(options);
  return response;
}
```

Please advise.

Comment: What do you mean `moving the 'require' lower will fix it`?

Comment: sorry, it was true in a previous revision. Removed.